# Copy Files on Build without .sln files - Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, build

I have a project in VS that doesn't have a .sln file in it, let's say it's a Java project (or any unmanaged code. However, I'd like to copy everything: the root folder and all of it's subdirectories over to another folder (eventually in the same domain) after Build. Is there an easier way to do this than include an empty .csproj and use MSBuild to copy?

The folder structure looks something like:

```
{Root}
   |A
     |C
   |B
     ...
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are asking.  Are you trying to copy _output files_ after builds or the project, source, and output files after builds?  What do you mean about using an empty `.csproj` and MSBuild to copy?  Presumably you have a `.csproj` for the project even if you don't retain/source control a `.sln` file for it.

Comment: Sorry about the vague info, I've updated it. I'd like to copy the project, source, and output files after building. There wouldn't be a .csproj to begin with, but I could definitely add an empty .csproj if that's the best way to copy everything over (with MSBuild). I tried just using a Powershell script, but that gave me errors (couldn't find local files on machine). Does this help?